# RDS deployment redirect not working correctly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a 2 server 2012R2 RDS deployment.

1. svr1: gateway,rd web,broker,host,licensing
2. svr2: host,licensing

If I select svr1 and set it to not accept new connections in server manager, then connect to svr1 I can't connect:
[image]

What I was expecting to happen would be that svr1 would just redirect to svr2. I'm I misunderstanding how this works? I thought this setting just made it refuse new desktop instances, but that a broker would be smart enough to redirect still. Do I need to have 2 brokers in an HA setup for this to work?